# Retrieve database information and check results for certain conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for the most efficient method to do the following...

I have a table with three fields: *id*, *eventid* and *movetype* - and I have the following code to query the database for all entries with a matching *eventid* :

```
$get_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE eventid='$eventid'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_results)){
    // store results in array
    $move_type_array = explode(" ", $row['movetype']);
}
```

Please note: *movetype* can only be three values: Internal, Outgoing, Incoming

Using a set of dummy data, **var_dump($move_type_array)** could output:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Internal" } array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Internal" }
```

Another example of an output would be:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Internal" } array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Incoming" } array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Outgoing" }
```

I then need to check the output to see if the following conditions are met:

1. Does the array contain **Internal** *twice*?
2. If the array only contains **Internal** *once*, then does the array also contain **Incoming** and **Outgoing**?

If either of the conditions are met then a message should be displayed telling them which condition has been met, otherwise a message should tell them that the conditions have not been met.

I have tried using a number of PHP functions such as in_array(), and also tried storing the data in a string and using preg_match() however I was unsuccessful in both methods.

Comment: Do you need to check this for all the rows or for every row? Does it mean movetype can be something like 'Internal Outgoing Incoming' altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT SUM(IF(movetype = 'Internal', 1, 0)) AS internal, 
           SUM(IF(movetype = 'Outgoing', 1, 0)) AS outgoing, 
           SUM(IF(movetype = 'Incoming', 1, 0)) AS incoming
    FROM table
    WHERE eventid = $eventid
    GROUP BY eventid
");
$count = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($count['internal'] >= 2 || ($count['internal'] == 1 
        && $count['outgoing'] >= 1 
        && $count['incoming'] >= 1)) {
    echo 'Yes';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1. Don't use '*' - fetch only required fields!
// 2. Don't use mysql_* functions - they are obsolete! Use PDO or MySQLi instead.
$get_results = mysql_query("SELECT `movetype` FROM table WHERE eventid='$eventid'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_results)){

    // Count the values
    $arr = array_count_values(explode(" ", $row['movetype']));

    // Check them here
    if(isset($arr['Internal'])) {

        if($arr['Internal'] === 2)
            echo ' Internal: 2'.PHP_EOL;
        else if($arr['Internal'] === 1
            && isset($arr['Incoming'])
            && isset($arr['Outgoing']))
            echo ' Internal: 1, Incoming and Outgoing'.PHP_EOL;

    }
}
```

Comment: The code would execute up until the second check: (if($arr['Internal'] === 2) - and would go no further. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: You should better examine the code rather than blindly copy / paste that.

Comment: I did not blindly copy and paste the code - $arr['Internal'] was returning a value of 11 when Internal appeared twice in the array. I did not understand why. Also is there any reason why you have double a double isset() check?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have fixed isset() issue. You can always use print_r() or var_dump() on that $arr to see what is inside.